# Dropdown with search -

Tags: html, jquery, css

When i focus and select from up and down arrows key it is not working please can you help me with this.

Here is my code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 200px;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <select id='country' name="country" style='width: 200px;'>
                <optgroup label='div1'>
                    <option value='1'>India</option>
                    <option value='2'>America</option> 
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label='div2'>
                    <option value='3'>Pakistan </option>
                    <option value='4'>Afghanistan</option> 
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#country").select2();

            $("#country").on("select2:open", function (e) {
                // Highlight the initially selected option
                highlightSelected();
            });

            $("#country").on("select2:select", function (e) {
                // Highlight the selected option when selected via mouse
                highlightSelected();
            });

            // Listen for keydown events
            $("#country").on("keydown", function (e) {
                var currentOption = $(this).find(":selected");
                var highlightedOption;

                if (e.which === 38) { // Up arrow
                    highlightedOption = currentOption.prev();
                } else if (e.which === 40) { // Down arrow
                    highlightedOption = currentOption.next();
                }

                if (highlightedOption.length > 0) {
                    $(this).find("option").removeClass("highlight");
                    highlightedOption.addClass("highlight");
                }
            });

            function highlightSelected() {
                var selectedOption = $("#country").find(":selected");
                $("#country").find("option").removeClass("highlight");
                selectedOption.addClass("highlight");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to when i focus element from dropdown then it should work for up and down arrows from keyboard.
...........................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 200px;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <select id='country' name="country" style='width: 200px;'>
                <optgroup label='div1'>
                    <option value='1'>India</option>
                    <option value='2'>America</option> 
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label='div2'>
                    <option value='3'>Pakistan </option>
                    <option value='4'>Afghanistan</option> 
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#country").select2();

            $("#country").on("select2:open", function (e) {
                highlightSelected();
            });

            $("#country").on("select2:select", function (e) {
                highlightSelected();
            });

            $("#country").on("select2:selecting", function (e) {

                $("#country").find("option").removeClass("highlight");
            });

            function highlightSelected() {

                var selectedOption = $("#country").find(":selected");
                $("#country").find("option").removeClass("highlight");
                selectedOption.addClass("highlight");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not working as i was expecting when i focus on dropdown element and then i click on up or down arrows from keyboard it should work but it is not working for given code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.